# Can not access Cluster Ip with same Node

Tags: kubernetes, flannel

I'm Deploying a k8s cluster on CentOS with version of v1.5.1

Having three nodes:

- `kube-01`(master)
- `kube-02`
- `kube-03`

Having a deployment with one pod, named `Deployment-A` with a pod ip `Pod-A-IP`, deployed on `kube-03`

Having a deployment with two pods, named `Deployment-B`. Each work node has one pod. We call `Pod-B-02` on `kube-02` and `Pod-B-03` on `kube-03`

Exposing `Deployment-A` using type NodePort, I have a Cluster IP `Service-A-IP`

- `Pod-B-02` access `Service-A-IP`, OK
- `Pod-B-03` access `Service-A-IP`, time out
- `kube-02` access `Service-A-IP`, OK
- `kube-03` access `Service-A-IP`, OK

It seems that accessing a Service from pods in same Node with the Service's backend will encounter this problem.

---

### Updated on Mon Feb 20 16:22:47 CST 2017

I have captured the [network traffic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIcf7.png) on `Pod-B-03`

- `10.244.1.10` is the pod ip of `Pod-B-03`
- `10.107.25.245` is `Service-A-IP`
- `10.244.1.2` is `Pod-A-IP`

I'm using flannel. I suggested there is something wrong with flannel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you describe is something that I had in the past if I remember correct...but I had many network problems with many different error sources. If it is really the same issue, then probably setting `net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables` and `net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ip6tables` to 1 may help. You could try this on all hosts first:

```
sysctl -w net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables=1
sysctl -w net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ip6tables=1
```

Then check the service networking again without rebooting your machine. If this helps, persist the change into `/etc/sysctl.conf` or `/etc/sysctl.d/`

Kubernetes network problems tend to have uncountable sources of errors, making it really hard to debug this without enough information. It would be good if you could provide some additional information about how you did setup the cluster (kube-up, kargo, kops, kubeadm, ...), which cloud you use (or bare-metal?) and which network solution you chose (weave, calico, cloud provider based, ...)

It may also help to see the output of `iptables -L -t nat` and the kube-proxy logs as most service related problems can be debugged with this information.

**EDIT** I've just found the Kubernetes issue where I had this solution from: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/33798